# How to get internal sounds working with Macbook

Tags: gnome, sound, microphone, macbook

How to get internal sounds working with Macbook? I am using Ubuntu 10.10. Sounds work when I use headset, but internal sounds doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need newer sound drivers.  Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/InstallingLinuxAlsaDriverModules.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a quirk that you need to work out with the Mac Ubuntu guides here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook

These should tell you how to identify your MacBook and then introduce you to a guide which should tell you about incompatibilities.

Comment: That page doesn't have guide for this model. I have tried guide for the latest version, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your mac is newer than any of those? Hmm perhaps it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

On many Macs the internal speakers at muted, you may to unmute them with alsamixer or gnome-alsamixer.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't work.